# std::get_time not working for date in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, std

I am trying to parse a date and time string using std::get_time in visual studio 2012. The time string seems to parse correctly but not the date string. I want to eventually convert the date string to an integer for comparison. I am aware that I can manually parse it, but I was wondering whether I am missing something regarding the use of std::get_time. Here is a sample code with output.

```
struct std::tm time, date;
std::istringstream ss( "09/02/2017 23:19:12" );
std::string ss1, ss2;
ss >> ss1 >> ss2;
std::stringstream iss1( ss1 ), iss2( ss2 );
iss1 >> std::get_time( &date, "%m/%d/%Y" );
iss2 >> std::get_time( &time, "%H:%M:%S" );
std::cout << date.tm_mon << "/" << date.tm_mday << "/" << date.tm_year << ", " << time.tm_hour << ":" << time.tm_min << ":" << time.tm_sec << "\n";
```

The output I get is

```
8/2/117, 23:19:12
```

Comment: So you print the internal representation of the date. What is your problem here?

Comment: How do I get the actual date (actual month, day and year) using std::get_time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way it works!

`struct tm` stores months as 0-11 but days as 1-31. And year is number of years since 1900.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm